# install4j - Events for Installation Components screen

Tags: install4j

Is there any event associated with Install Components Screen?

Something like Next button disabled initially, and upon selection of a component, Next gets enabled. I see this happening for the License screen. Why dont we have it for Installation Components screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute arbitrary code by setting the "Selection script" property of the "Installation components" screen, for example to

```
context.getWizardContext().setNextButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thansk, Ingo. Is "Selection Script" a new property in later versions? I am using 4.2.7.

Comment: Yes, that property was added in 5.0